Drive APIで共有ドライブに権限を割り振ったあとの、氏名の取得について
GASで、Google Drive API v2を使用して
Googleアカウント(一般アカウント)に設定されている氏名を取得して、リストと照合するために
テスト用の共有ドライブに一度権限を割り当てたあとに
そのレスポンスから氏名を取得しています。
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/permissions/insert?hl=ja
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/permissions?hl=ja#Permission
const response = Drive.Permissions.insert(permission, DirID, options)
console.log(response.name)

これで取得出来るのは
https://myaccount.google.com/profile/name
で設定している氏名だと思っているのですが
これで取得した氏名が
↑のアカウント設定の氏名と一致しない場合があります。
(https://myaccount.google.com/profile/profile-discovery
も確認しました)
response.name

で取得しているのは、どの設定の項目でしょうか…？
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

自己解決したので、共有します。
https://myaccount.google.com/profile/profile-discovery のプロフィール検索を有効にしていないと、アドレスが有効にして名前を設定している場合は、その名前が呼び出されるようです。
